# How to get ListView SelectedItem while editing?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to save record when combination of keys pressed Ctrl + S.
Below code works fine only when i exit TextBox and select line then press Ctrl + S.
How to SelectItem without exiting TextBox? For example: typing text >> Ctrl + S >> continue typing.
Here is my code:

```
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
        {
            sql.saveSoftwareChanges(_list.SelectedItem as Software);
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

and XAML:

```
            <ListView x:Name="_list" Visibility="Visible" KeyDown="_list_KeyDown">

            <!--RESOURCES-->
            <ListView.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF9A" />
                        </Trigger>

                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <!--/RESOURCES-->

            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>

                    <GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button x:Name="_save" Content="Save" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Click="_save_Click" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Product ID">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding productId}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Product">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding product}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                     </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Path">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding path}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Master Path">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding master_path}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Parameters">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding parameters}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Windows Version">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding windowsVersion}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Where do you call this code? Is it in list box key press event?

Comment: from ListView, see updated code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of research and trial and error I've got the solution.
It's as simple as moving out of that field, which can be achieved by:

```
MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

and entire method looks like:

```
        if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.S))
        {
            var uie = e.OriginalSource as UIElement;
            uie.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
            sql.saveSoftwareChanges(_list.SelectedItem as Software);

            uie.Focus();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

I hope that will help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your save code in a function then call this function from any control that may have the focus at that time. (i.e. the text box as  well).
Remember that keyboard events only fire when the corresponding control has focus.

Test this:

```
<ListView x:Name="_list" Visibility="Visible" KeyDown="_list_KeyDown">

        <!--RESOURCES-->
        <ListView.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFF9A" />
                    </Trigger>

                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ListView.Resources>
        <!--/RESOURCES-->

        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>

                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button x:Name="_save" Content="Save" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Click="_save_Click" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Product ID">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding productId}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2" KeyDown="_list_KeyDown"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Product">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding product}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2" KeyDown="_list_KeyDown"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                 </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Path">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding path}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2" KeyDown="_list_KeyDown"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Master Path">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding master_path}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2" KeyDown="_list_KeyDown"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Parameters">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding parameters}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2" KeyDown="_list_KeyDown"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Windows Version">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding windowsVersion}" MinWidth="20" Width="AUTO" Padding="2" KeyDown="_list_KeyDown"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Please tell me about the error. I think KeyDown events of textbox and listbox has different signitures so you can't use them in this way.

Comment: there is no error. it just won't save, it fires messagebox from msql so that part works ok, but it wont save it as nothing was passed to this method

Comment: I missed something. You are using Listbox.SelectedItem which wont work for the listbox with no focus. The solution that I can think of is to use Listbox.LostFocus event to capture selected item at that moment then record that and use that object to call your save function. Remember to manually apply current state of the textbox in that object

Comment: it sorted problem partially. It captures all changes in whole row but last edited field.